# Convention for making database .on calls with Firebase, React-Native, Redux?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

Where is a good place to do this? I've tried calling the action creators that make the `.on` calls inside of `componentWillMount` however this racks up multiple of the same listeners between view changes. Also at some point you need to call `.off` on all these listeners. Whats the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. [...]. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

I would instead recommend adding your listeners in [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). As you point out, you are not unsubscribing from the listeners. For that, you can use [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount).